# [ROS2] Call launch file from another launch file

Tags: ros, ros2, include

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

Is it possible (and how) to call a launch file from another launch file? I believe that was possible on ROS with the "include" tag, but I do not know how to do it on ROS2 with the .launch.py file.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/363687/%5Bros2%5D-call-launch-file-from-another-launch-file./) by [jeferrandiz](https://answers.ros.org/users/60816/jeferrandiz/) on ROS Answers with karma: 27 on 2020-10-19

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The `LaunchDescription` can be used.

This was discussed in the past at https://answers.ros.org/question/306935/ros2-include-a-launch-file-from-a-launch-file/.

An example in Autoware.auto:
https://gitlab.com/autowarefoundation/autoware.auto/AutowareAuto/-/blob/master/src/tools/autoware_auto_avp_demo/launch/ms3_core. launch.py

---

Originally posted by [miura](https://answers.ros.org/users/59801/miura/) with karma: 1908 on 2020-10-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1